# Add 30 minutes to a Time field using formula

Tags: formula, time

I'm trying to set a formula time field as the result of **adding 30 minutes to a time field** that returns TRUE in the following comparison.:

Time formula field is:

```
TimeEndWorkingHoursControl__c = TIMEVALUE(SelectedEndWorkingHours__c) + (0.5 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
```

Boolean formula field is:

```
IF(TIMENOW() = TimeEndWorkingHoursControl__c ,TRUE,FALSE)
```

As far as i know TIMENOW() returns time in GMT value, but mine is GMT+1, so probably that will never match. I'm pretty sure that's never gonna be a TRUE.

Maybe that would be correct?

```
IF((TIMENOW() + (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) = TimeEndWorkingHoursControl__c,TRUE,FALSE)
```